# Using group by in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains `factorId`, `amount`, `remain` columns.

I need to calculate sum `amount`  and `remain` columns separately  grouped by `factorId`

Comment: So what is the *problem* here?

Comment: i want to calculate sum of two column using linq

Comment: I'm rolling back the code example because it was not made by the OP, and was only speculation.

Comment: I don't think that the topic should have been flagged. The question provided more than enough information to get answered.

Comment: Two downvotes with no explanation.  Bit cheeky, that.  We should really be helping each other to learn.

Comment: @RobLyndon - completely agree with you on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line:

```
var groupedList = myList
    .GroupBy(i => i.factorId)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        FactorId = g.Key, 
        SumAmount = g.Sum(i => i.Amount), 
        SumRemains = g.Sum(i => i.Remains) 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var groupedList = myList.GroupBy(i => i.factorId);
var results = groupedList.Select(g => new { SumAmount = g.Sum(i => i.Amount), SumRemains = g.Sum(i => i.Remains) });
```

Comment: Come on now, you can do that in one line. :)

Comment: OK, I'll vote you up.  I bet Resharper would have told me that if I'd typed it in.

Comment: OP, you should use Joe's solution.  I forgot to include the key in mine.